# Understanding difference in .Result behavior based on when in the request stack it is called

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, async-await

Inside a MVC app, I have a Controller action that calls an async MethodA() which in turn calls an async MethodB(). MethodB() makes an awaitable call to another api.A calling method calls MethodA() with an await keyword. MethhodA() calls MethodB(), like this, MethodB().Result. This leads to a deadlock.

```
 private async Task<bool> MethodA()
 {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"MethodA Start: {DateTime.UtcNow}");
        var response =  MethodB().Result;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"MethodA End: {DateTime.UtcNow}");
        return response;
 }

 public async Task<bool> MethodB()
 {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"MethodB start : {DateTime.UtcNow}");
        using (var httpclient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await httpclient.GetAsync(new Uri("http://localhost:62757/api/values"));
        }
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"MethodB ending : {DateTime.UtcNow}");
        return true;
 }
```

This leads to a deadlock with an output:
    MethodA Start: 04/08/2018 1:28:56
    MethodB start : 04/08/2018 1:28:56

However, When I move the .Result out of MethodA() on to MethodB()'s call to the API, it does not cause a deadlock.

```
    private async Task<bool> MethodA()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"MethodA Start: {DateTime.UtcNow}");
        var response =  await MethodB();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"MethodA End: {DateTime.UtcNow}");
        return response;
    }

    public async Task<bool> MethodB()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"MethodB start : {DateTime.UtcNow}");
        using (var httpclient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = httpclient.GetAsync(new Uri("http://localhost:62757/api/values")).Result;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Response from 3rd party recieved : {DateTime.UtcNow}");
        }
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"MethodB ending : {DateTime.UtcNow}");
        return true;
    }
```

This logic executes without a deadlock with output
MethodA Start: 04/08/2018 1:38:05
MethodB start : 04/08/2018 1:38:05
Response from 3rd party received : 04/08/2018 1:38:07
MethodB ending : 04/08/2018 1:38:07
MethodA End: 04/08/2018 1:38:07

I am struggling to understand the difference of these 2 scenarios. Why does .Result on an external api call not cause a deadlock, however an internal call with .Result cause a deadlock. Greatly appreciate help in understanding this behavior. Thanks in advance.

NOTE: It is recommended to use async/await all the way to the top. I am aware of this. The goal of this implementation was to understand the behavior of .Result thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

Practically, when we use await into async method its work as a thread. Sometimes we need to waiting for a result to another process run or we use async method into non async method. That time we use .Result. But another way to confiure await into async method that is set to ConfigureAwait false.

Like as

```
var response = await MethodB().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: thanks for your thoughts. It does not really answer my question, the code you mentioned above does not explain the difference in behavior of .Result. My question is about understanding the behavior of .Result in different scenarios. I am not looking out for alternate solutions.

Comment: await asynchronously unwraps the result of your task, whereas just using Result would block until the task had completed.